# Alignment of moving average in geom_ma

Tags: r, ggplot2, moving-average

- I'm trying to rework some old code to plot 7-day moving averages.
- The old code uses `zoo::rollmean` with default alignment as centre
- When I use `geom_ma` from the `tidyquant` package the default alignment is right.
- I'm using the simple moving average `ma_fun = SMA`

Is there a parameter than can be passed to `geom_ma` in my plot that can align the moving average to centre?

I did read the docs for `geom_ma` and was directed to `TTR::SMA()`. This has a offset parameter that can take a percentile as an alignment of the distribution. The parameter was ignored in my code.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: John, would you care making this a reproducible question? (i.e., some sample data etc)

Comment: ?geom_ma also says: `Seven options are available including: SMA, EMA, WMA, DEMA, ZLEMA, VWMA, and EVWMA. The default is SMA. See TTR::SMA() for underlying functions.` Without looking into the source code, this sounds to me as if you cannot pass specific parameters to the functions and only specific defaults are chosen. But maybe the argument accepts actual functions, e.g., `geom_ma(..., ma_fun = function(x) TTR::SMA(x, ... [yourparameters]))`

Answer (score 1):

you could use `seismicRoll` package using `roll_mean` argument that has an align argument similar to `zoo::rollmean`. I think the offset parameter is for ALMA() only, and SMA(what geom_ma is using) does not have that parameter.

Using tq data for demo, red line shows realigned MA to center, yellow highlights how geom_ma (dotted line) is right aligned.

```
AAPL <- tq_get("AAPL", from = "2013-01-01", to = "2016-12-31")

AAPL %>% 
    mutate(rolling_mean1 = seismicRoll::roll_mean(adjusted, n = 50, align = "right"),
           rolling_mean2 = seismicRoll::roll_mean(adjusted, n = 50, align = "center")) %>% 
ggplot() +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = rolling_mean1), color = "yellow",size = 4)+
geom_ma(aes(x = date, y = adjusted), ma_fun = SMA, n = 50, size = 3) +
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = rolling_mean2), color = "red")
```

[image]